# Do key hashes include an equals sign?

Tags: android, facebook, hash, key

When I generated my Android key hash (for Facebook), I noticed that there was an equals sign at the end. Are you supposed to include that when you register your key hash with Facebook developers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you do. The key hash is [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded, and the equals sign is part of the encoded string.

A base64-encoded string is terminated by 0, 1 or 2 equals signs that are used as padding. The padding indicates the number of bytes that needs to be used to decode the last block of the string. More details can be found in the linked Wikipedia article.